# Plotting relationship between more than two variables

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a function `f[a,b,c]` and would like to plot the values of `f[a,b,c]` for a range of $\frac{a}{b}$ and a range of $c$. That is, I'd like to see the change in the function over various $\frac{a}{b}$ for each value of $c$. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can `f[a,b,c] = a+b+c`. If yes then you would have to specify either `a` or `b` right. Or is the function only made of ratios of `a/b` and `c`.

Comment: @Hubble07 Yes, it can be expressed as $a + b + c$. However I'd like to constrain the ratio of $a$ and $b$ though, without setting either value.

Comment: Does your `f` satisfy a "homogeneity relation"; i.e., a relationship between `f[a, b, c]` and `f[a/b, 1, c]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your function be simply `a+b+c` then you can do the following:

```
f[d_, c_] := Module[{a = 1, b},
b = a/d;
a + b + c]


Plot[{f[d, 1], f[d, 2]}, {d, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]